How do I style a volume slider created using range:input
WHERE I USED MY RANGE INPUT AS VOLUME SLIDER
<RangeInput
 min={0}
 max={1}
 step="any"
 value={volume}
 onChange={(e: BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
  if (video) {
   setVolume(e.target.valueAsNumber);
   video.volume = e.target.valueAsNumber;
   handleVolumeLevel();
  }
  }}
 onClick={handleVolumeBarClick}
 ref={volumeBarContainerRef}
 containerClassName={showVolume ? "w-16 scale-x-100" : "w-0 scale-x-0"}
 // containerWidth={64}
/>

WHERE I SET UP MY RANGE INPUT FOR ANY INPUT SLIDER
import React, { BaseSyntheticEvent, RefObject } from 'react';

interface RangeInputProps {
    min?: number;
    max?: number;
    value: number;
    step?: string;
    onChange?: (e: BaseSyntheticEvent) => void;
    containerClassName?: string;
    className?: string;
    onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    ref?: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
}

export const RangeInput: React.FC<RangeInputProps> = ({
    min = 0,
    max = 100,
    value,
    step,
    onChange,
    containerClassName, //set the width of the container and optionally the scale
    className,
    onClick,
    ref,
}) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div className={`grid items-center ${containerClassName} transition-all duration-150 ease-in-out transform-origin-left focus-within:w-16 focus-within:scale-x-100`}>
                <input
                    type="range"
                    min={min}
                    max={max}
                    value={value}
                    step={step}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    className={`${className} w-full rounded-lg`}
                    onClick={onClick}
                    ref={ref}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

MY CSS FOR ALL RANGE INPUT
input[type="range"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: max-content;
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track:hover {
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track:hover {
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #5229E1;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    background-color: #5229E1;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}


I was trying to customize my volume slider. It works fine but I want to make the background to the left side of the thumb purple and the background to the right side of the thumb white as it is. More details in the image.

Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730877/how-to-make-the-left-side-of-a-range-slider-a-different-color-than-the-right-sid

https://www.sitepoint.com/css-custom-range-slider/
